# Java FileHandler to use 24 hour time

Tags: java, filehandler

I have a FileHandler set up:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.class.getName());
FileHandler handler = new FileHandler(myFile, true);
handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
logger.addHandler(handler);
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```

However my server is in UTC, so in my log file, the timestamps look like: `Nov 9, 2012 5:12:17 PM`

This is harder to understand in a pinch, so I would like to know if it is possible

1) To convert this to 24 hour time, so at least I would see `17:12:17` instead of `5:12:17PM`
2) To instead use a different time zone

I think it might be something about how I set up the formatter, but I just don't know how.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by creating my own formatter using an example I found:

[Custom logger formatter](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/458.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the javadoc of [SimpleFormatter.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format%28java.util.logging.LogRecord%29), you may specify your own format via java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format property in the [application logging configuration file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a1.8).

The default properties file is <Java home>\jre7\lib\logging.properties. Copy it and put it wherever you want.

The [Java Logging Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) is a good reading too.

The following code

```
System.setProperty(
   "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$s: %5$s [%1$tc]%n" );
Logger l = Logger.getLogger("");
l.warning( "Hello" );
```

outputs

```
WARNING: Hello [ven. nov. 09 20:26:30 CET 2012]
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works.  Right now I don't have a logging configuration file, or a `LogRecord` object (which `format` requires).   Is there something more like `SimpleFormatter().format("HH:mm:ss");` I might be able to use?

Comment: Thank you!  I found the file and property in my environment, and changed it as you recommended.  I restarted my Java process, but I'm still seeing the same in the old format.  Anything else I might need to restart to get the new property to take?

Comment: The properties file you've edited is not in use, your application use another file. search for 'logging.properties' in the app directory

Comment: I searched for 'logging.properties' in the '/' directory.  I saw two, one in `usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/` and one in `/etc/java-6-openjdk/`  and both look the same: `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%4$s: [%1$tc]%n %5$s`

Comment: ? No, there is no comment in front of them

Comment: Try to set the property via the code in the main() of your application, before any call to Logger or LoggerManager

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it to work in a simple case, copy pasting what you have above.  However, in my example, I am keeping a static reference to the logger, defined above the entry point for the application which I think might prevent me from getting this to work